# Can't mount ext4 partition via SATA to USB cable

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I'm stuck mounting an SSD, which is pre-formatted as ext4, via SATA to USB cable. However it gives the error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

This problem does not happen when plugging the SSD directly to the drive bay of the laptop. The problem is also not the cable, because it can mount a HDD formatted as FAT32.

Comment: It is possible that your 'sata to usb cable' adapter is not compatible with your SSD.

Comment: How could it happen? The ssd uses the global SATA interface

Comment: It has happened to me: an old adapter can not manage some new SSDs. In one particular case with an SSD I think the problem is that the adapter was confused by the physical sector size (512 bytes/sector is OK, but not 4096 bytes/sector). In another case there is a problem with a big HDD (2 TB), and I found that it could not manage big HDDs (but works well with smaller HDDs (for example 500 GB). - I think the problem can be in the electronic circuits of the adapter.

Comment: maybe you're right. I changed the adapter to use the hdd box and it's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're attempting to mount the device and not the right partition.

Please update your question as to see the mount command you are executing.

Make sure you don't have an USB memory stick, that is taking /dev/sdc

Execute this command to see all the partitions and paste the output:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

Assuming /dev/sdc is the right one, print the partition table to make sure which one is the right one to mount:

For example:

```
carles@fast:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sde

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sde: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xee845f97

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sde1        2048 1953525167 1953523120 931.5G 83 Linux

Command (m for help):
```

Cheers

Comment: This is the output: $ cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name
   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1     541696 sda1
   8        2     102400 sda2
   8        3      16384 sda3
   8        4  668265970 sda4
   8        5     632832 sda5
   8        6  153600000 sda6
   8        7  153600000 sda7
   7        8      31832 loop8
   7        9      52268 loop9
   8       16  976762583 sdc

Comment: $ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.
The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.
Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x0bf70db9.

Comment: Command (m for help): p Disk /dev/sdc: 931,53 GiB, 1000204885504 bytes, 1953525167 sectors Disk model: External Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x4d36ec1c

Comment: From the output of my system, the device /dev/sdc1 is not shown. It's probably not created.

Comment: Yes @kstn it seems that you didn't create the partition or if you created, the table or partitions has disappeared. What command do you use to attempt to mount it?.

Comment: the partition /dev/sdc1 is not created because of the adapter. I changed to use the hdd box and it's fine now. The mount command is typical: mount /dev/sdc1 /media/WORK. It's also noted that the connection is more stable with a USB cable with ferrite choke.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mount "/dev/sdc", that's the disk. The partition should be "/dev/sdc1" or some other number.

regards.